# How to configure Jenkins with .NET Core in Openshift?

Tags: jenkins, .net-core, openshift, continuous-deployment, openshift-3

Openshift provides a standard Jenkins template with preinstalled tools allowing us to execute `oc` commands. If we want to build NodeJS apps we can install [NodeJS plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin). If we want to build .NET apps we can use [MSBuild plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/MSBuild+Plugin). But there's no .NET Core plugin. In virtually all resources online people just install .NET Core CLI using apt-get (or different app management tools) on the Jenkins machine directly.

How to properly build .NET Core applications in Jenkins within Openshift environment? Should I provision Jenkins pod with .NET Core CLI using some scripts? Can I use some custom image to create slave Jenkins instance with .NET Core CLI preinstalled ([this link suggests that way](https://github.com/redhat-developer/dotnet-jenkins-slave))? What's the recommended way?

Answer (score 1):

For using the dotnet-jenkins-slave images, there is information in the Red Hat documentation: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/net_core/2.2/html/getting_started_guide/gs_dotnet_on_openshift#using_jenkins.

There is also a blog post on Red Hat developer blog on this topic: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/10/17/ci-cd-for-net-core-container-applications-on-red-hat-openshift/.